# Why do we need memory mapped IO?

Tags: memory, operating-system, hardware

Why do we need memory-mapped IO? From what I learned in CS class, MMIO abstracts away the specific instructions to control a device. But, if the device's control registers (and thus what each memory cell in its part of the address space) depend on the make and model of the device, what's gained in terms of abstraction?

Comment: What do you suggest as an alternative?  How else can current CPU access I/O devices?  OK, some architectures have a separate I/O map with different timings and instructions, but  the map is accessed by index, ie 'address'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fundamentally, for a CPU to be able to perform IO it needs a way to read and write data to devices. There are many ways this could be done, such as a dedicated CPU instruction like IN/OUT on x86. MMIO is another solution that has proven popular for simplifying hardware designs.

On a typical CPU the core(s) will all be connected to a common bus that allows the cores to read/write to main memory and perhaps shared caches. The bus however is agnostic as to the source, destination and contents of the data. Thus, transfers on the bus could go to different memory controllers, different cores, caches, .ect. As a result the hardware designers can simply connect IO devices to this bus and the devices end up being accessed via the same mechanisms as RAM. This comes with some advantages:

- IO hardware can now directly retrieve data from RAM or other IO devices without the cores being involved mastering cycles
- CPU caching hardware can snoop transactions generated by IO to keep caches coherent
- The CPUs can be performing useful work while data is being moved on the bus, instead of the cores waiting for each load/store to complete.
- No special instructions need to be supported by the CPU for IO

Most of these advantages are obscured from software, hence my argument that MMIO benefits the hardware designers.

Answer (score 2):

Every device has some sort of internal registers that software (device drivers) use to control the device's state, ask the device to do things, and determine status.

There are 2 main ways that software (device drivers) can access a device's internal registers - by mapping those registers into the CPUs physical address space (the same way that memory is mapped into the CPUs physical address space); and by providing a dedicated mechanism (e.g. IO ports on 80x86).

To understand the advantages/disadvantages; it's best to think about the nature of communication between CPU/s and memory. This communication needs to be extremely fast because everything depends on it; and (for electronics) "fast" tends to mean simple, with short bus lengths (due to things like capacitance and resistance) and with the least loads (because each load increases the current needed to drive the bus, which means larger transistors to handle the higher current, which means more time taken for transistors to switch). Of course there's also a bunch of tricks to make it even faster, starting with caches (and maybe cache coherency), and prefetching, and speculative execution to keep the CPU busy while it's waiting for data.

By providing a dedicated mechanism (e.g. IO ports on 80x86) it all seems nice; because you'd have separation between the high speed memory bus and all the (much slower) stuff.

What if we slap a honking great mess right in the middle of the most performance critical data path (between CPU and RAM), so that software (device drivers) can access devices' internal registers using memory mapped IO instead? Oh boy...

For a start you'd be looking at some major complications for caches (at a minimum, some way to say "these area/s should be cached, and those area/s shouldn't be cached" with all the logic to figure out which accesses are/aren't cached, and its added latency); plus more major complications for the CPU itself (can/should it try to prefetch? Can/should it speculatively execute past a read/write?); plus slower (longer with more loads) and/or more expensive bus to handle "who knows what device/s might get plugged in", likely with some extra pain (wait states, etc) to deal devices being so much slower than memory. It just sounds like an incredibly bad idea.

However, it turns out that a lot of devices can benefit from being able to access the memory bus directly (using bus mastering/DMA to transfer data between the device and RAM directly; and not for memory mapped IO), so you mostly end up wanting that slower bus anyway, and you mostly end up wanting to deal with all the other complications too.

If you look at the history (at least for 80x86); you'll find a gradual shift from "simple, primarily using IO ports" to "extremely complex, primarily using memory mapped IO".

> Why do we need memory mapped IO?

No, it's not a strict necessity (but it's much nicer if you're willing to accept the performance/complexity consequences).

Comment: Thanks @Brendan. I have been struggling to understand this whole `memory mapped i/o` thingy and your first 2 paragraphs clicked to me. Regarding the advantages you mentioned - apart from hardware architecture simplification does `mmap` approach has benefits in terms of performance when we read/write files to disk ?